# Using parts of GLTF as an InstancedMesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been practicing cloning an [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_instancing_scatter.html) code in three.js repo.

In this example, there is something I don't understand.

Why THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry should be copied by THREE.BufferGeomtry.prototype?

```
loader.load( './models/gltf/Flower/Flower.glb', function ( gltf ) {

            const _stemMesh = gltf.scene.getObjectByName( 'Stem' );
            const _blossomMesh = gltf.scene.getObjectByName( 'Blossom' );

            stemGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();
            blossomGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

            THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.copy.call( stemGeometry, _stemMesh.geometry );
            THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype.copy.call( blossomGeometry, _blossomMesh.geometry );
```

maybe it's about javascript, but still, I don't get it.

Why can't I use InstancedBufferGeometry.copy() directly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry should be copied by THREE.BufferGeomtry.prototype?

`InstancedBufferGeometry` is a sub class of `BufferGeometry` with an overwritten `copy()` method. If you would use `InstancedBufferGeometry.copy()` directly, the method would try to copy an `InstancedBufferGeometry` specific property called `instanceCount` from a `BufferGeometry`. So the property of the derived class would become `undefined`.